# JQuery not fully running on "back" on Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a page with multiple videos that randomize order on load. When I go directly on the website using google chrome the randomizing works perfectly, but if I go on off on a linked page and hit "back" to go back to the video the page, the page has the same video in every iframe (there are total of 11 videos). On shift+reload it works again.

How can I get rid of this issue? I tried adding an empty function but I think that's as far as I can go with my current knowledge -_-
I found this code on the web btw.

Any helps is very much appreciated!!!

```
<script>
    //Randomize order of video chapters
    //Main statement, calls randomize function
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#videocontainer").randomize("div.chapter");
    });



    (function ($) {

        $.fn.randomize = function (childElem) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var elems = $this.children(childElem);

                //
                elems.sort(function () {
                    return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
                });

                $this.remove(childElem);

                //Populates array with newly obtained order
                for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
                    $this.append(elems[i]);

            });
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, `$(document).ready(function () {}` and `function ($) {}` are pretty much synonymous.

Comment: Are saying that having both in the same program is redundant? Or that I should only be using one of them? I grabbed this code from the net.

Comment: It's redundant, but it won't fix your problem. You can have the function declaration and the function call within `function ($) {}`.